# Project that uses CodeSmith to generate the table classes

Tags: codesmith

I just got the code source of a project from a friend. He used CodeSmith to generate the database and table classes but now i want to add one more table to the database. Obviously i dont have codesmith to regenerate the database so my question is if i can just use another ORM, like Dapper to use the new table called "users"?

Comment: What database are you using, SQL server?

Comment: Yes, that should work.  CodeSmith is likely just generating ADO.NET code, although I believe they have ORM templates as well.

Answer (score 0):

I work for CodeSmith Tools. I've seen first hand that it is better to stick with one tool / templates for future regeneration/additional features/new db tables. If you don't, managing the project long term will be a nightmare, especially when a change occurs database side.